Persist Session and Tokens After OAuth2 Sign-in Using Amplify Flutter
I'm developing a mobile app where users can log in through two methods: direct username/password login via Cognito Sign-In and OAuth2 sign-in with a third-party system.
For OAuth2 login, I redirect users to a '${identityURL}oauth2/authorize?$provider$redirection$responseType$clientId$scope$state' web page where they authenticate and obtain a code. Using this code, I then call the AWS Cognito '${identityURL}oauth2/token' API to retrieve tokens (id_token, access_token, and refresh_token).
Here's the body of the API request:
{
  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "client_id": "<poolId>",
  "redirect_uri": "<redirectionUrl>",
  "code": "<code>"
}

Upon a successful API call, I receive the tokens. Now, I want to use the Cognito Amplify Flutter library to create a session so that the user's authentication state and tokens persist across app restarts. How can I achieve this?
I'm looking for guidance on how to integrate these tokens into the Amplify Flutter framework effectively to manage sessions and facilitate easy token retrieval when needed.

For OAuth2.0 flow, are you registering these third-party providers such a Google, Facebook as Federated identity provider in Cognito user pool, or you are maintaining them independently.

It's not none of them. It's basically other authentication system we are using that authentication webpage for authorize user.

If that’s OIDC compliant, then I would recommend to register that inside Cognito user pool federated identity providers, and use Cognito Hosted UI where user can see both options, Cognito user name and password and your other OIDC provider.

I'm using this url and open it in webpage '${config.identityURL}oauth2/authorize?$provider$redirection$responseType$clientId$scope$state'  and getting authorization code i'm calling other api for fetch the tokens. so how can I implement it using amplify flutter so session will maintain using that tokens
